# How to call controller from the button click in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Please i am working on MVC website, i have a Search page and another search form on index page. I want to call the the same search page controller when i click the search button from index page. Below is how my button is on the index page.

```
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="addressSearch"   
          onclick="location.href='<%: @Url.Action("List", "Search") %>'">
     Search</button></span>
```

List is my search Action from search page and Search is the controller name. When i click the button above, it returns url in the form

http://localhost:52050/<%:%20/Search/List%20%>

Showing bad request . I am suspecting its from my Routing , I am not sure how to archieve this, Please any help would be appreciated .

Below is how my Routing is

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                url: "Page{page}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "Search", action = "List" }
                );


            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
            );
```

Comment: use @Html.Actionlink() instead of button for navigation purpose

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are mixing **razor** and **aspx** syntax,if your view engine is **razor** just do this:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="addressSearch"   
          onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("List", "Search")'">
```

Comment: Thank you man. Never though that would make a difference. Thank you so much

Comment: Yah will do that, now having quite difficult time with my Dropdown selected value. It is'nt changing. :(

Comment: What is `List` and `Search` respectively?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Action name name and control name i.e `public class SearchController` with `public ActionResult Search`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Ok, the parameters are `@Url.Action("Action","Controller")`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("DisplayText", "Action", "Controller", route, attribute)
```

in your code should be,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "List", "Search", new{@class="btn btn-info", @id="addressSearch"})
```